# Redimensioning bidimensional array gives error nº 9 "subscript out of range" in second iteration of loop: - Can't figure out the reason

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, runtime-error

This error is driving me crazy.

I followed all tutorials just in case but I can't figure out the reason my code is giving error nº9 in the line where I redim the array inside the loop.
It is happening in the second round of the loop.

Here is the code:

```
   Dim ar() As Variant
   Dim cont As Integer
   'Here goes some SQL and querying that works and does not matter for this post. The results are returned well.
  
   cont = 0
   Do Until rs.EOF
    resul = rs!f1 & " " & rs!f2
    'Error thrown in the second round of the loop in the following line:
    ReDim Preserve ar(cont, 1)
    ar(cont, 0) = rs!ID
    ar(cont, 1) = resul
    rs.MoveNext
    cont = cont + 1
Loop
```

I really can't figure out why is happening the error.
The syntax is Ok as far as tutorials say.
I wanted to create this bidimensional array so that I can attach it to a combobox.List in a userform.

Again, the recordset returned is ok, the problem seems to be the array at some point.

Comment: What is `cont` and in your code not relvant, is data returned into `ar()`?

Comment: @SamuelEverson I edited the question and added the "cont" variable declaration and initialization. I forgot to paste it but I already have it in the code.
There is not much that I omitted, just a string with an sql that I already tested that works and the sentenced with the db.opendatabase(sql).

Comment: Couldn't you do the concatenation in the SQL and use GetRows to populate the array?

Comment: @norie No. I tried populating the combobox with the array given by "getRows" but I get the columns nor sorted properly.

Comment: There's nothing in the posted code that refers to a combobox. How was the combobox not 'sorted' correctly? Did you try using Application.Transpose on the array returned when you use GetRows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MS documentation for ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement).

> If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. For example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array.

I haven't been able to recreate your error but believe it has something to do with the above.

Comment: that is a bit weird and unintuitive IMO.
I inverted the order of sizes, and now tired with ar(0, cont) in every statement where ar appears and it seems to work Ok, Thanks a lot. I looked up the documentation but did see that part...

Comment: @MisterEquis A step further forward: having restructured the dimension order, you need not transpose the array in order to assign it to the `.List` property, just assign the array to the control's `.Column` property :-)

Comment: @T.M. Now I think what is more efficient; to use rs.movelast, rs.movefirst and the the rs.getrows(rs.recordCount) and assign this to the .column property of the combobox, or traverse the recordset and use .additem and then .list(0,1) = value instead.
I tried it in both ways and like the .getrows solution more for being shorter, but I don't know if it could cause problems.
At this point I saw that creating an extra array is not necessary at all.